# Showing multiple forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In my code I have a main form (named frmMain) and an About Box(named AboutBox1). What I want to happen is when the user clicks on the Help menu in my menu strip and then clicks on About I want the AboutBox1 form to show. I've researched on how to do it but the intellisense is not recognizing the second form when I try and type and I have no idea why.
Any ideas?

The code that I'd assume that I put in my menu button click even is:

```
AboutBox1 aboutbox = new aboutbox();
aboutbox.ShowDialog();
```

however AboutBox1 gives an error that the type or namespace could not be found.

Here is the code I currently have. Along with this is also a newly created form that has nothing but the initial code in it:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5366535

Comment: Just so you know, using the `ShowDialog()` method creates a _modal_ dialog box (meaning, it will prevent you from clicking on anything else).  To keep things simple, you could just use `aboutbox.Show()`.  Please post all of your code to make helping you a bit easier.

Answer (score 5):

Try this :

```
AboutBox1 aboutbox = new AboutBox1();
aboutbox.ShowDialog();
```

`ShowDialog()` creates a modal window, if you need to create a modeless window you can use `Show()` method.

---

in C#

the typical way to initialize a object is

```
Classname variable_name = new Classname(); // assuming that constructor does not take any parameter
```

---

Go though this article once : [`Objects (C# Programming Guide)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173110.aspx) it will help you to understand a few basic things.

Answer (score 3):

If your class is named `AboutBox1` you need to use

```
AboutBox1 aboutbox = new AboutBox1();
```

to instantiate the `aboutbox` object of the type `AboutBox1`

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
AboutBox1 aboutbox = new aboutbox();
```

Is not a proper initialization of object in C# language. You should try to initialize the object in the following way:

```
AboutBox1 aboutbox = new AboutBox1();
```

Read more at MSDN:

- [Using Constructors (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx)
- [How to: Initialize Objects by Using an Object Initializer (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397680.aspx)
- [Classes and Structs (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173109.aspx)