# Accessing multiple forms in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to access a form from my main form of my project. The new forms name will be AboutBox1 and I want it to open when a user clicks on the About toolstrip button.

When I go to code in the About toolstrip button though the Intellisense does not recognize my new form (AboutBox1) that I had created

I have read that I need to create an instance of my new form however I'm not sure where or how to do that.

Below is the code that I have. (Ignore all the stuff in the middle, the toolbox button that needs to be clicked to access the new form is at the bottom)
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5366535

Comment: Yes, I know you added the link, but please provide the relevant lines of code in your post, in case the page 404's.

Comment: why are you asking the same question twice? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15956542/brand-new-to-c-need-help-showing-multiple-forms-in-vs

Answer (score 0):

in the onClick-Handler of you MenuItem:

```
//assuming AboutBox is derived from Form
AboutBox AboutBox1 = new AboutBox();
AboutBox1.Show(this);
```

Comment: It is not necessary to use `this` in your function call. Having a reference to the object is enough to get data into the second form. Having a reference to the parent form in the constructor is the best way to get data back, In My Opinion.

Comment: the difference is that the AboutBox will be modal if you use the call with the owner-parameter

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szcefbbd(v=vs.100).aspx) says `You can use this method to display a non-modal form.` This form will not be modal. Use `ShowDialog` to make it modal.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you need access to your form from outside the method, make a variable at the top of the class.

```
AboutBox1 frmAboutBox;

[STAThread]
...
```

But seeing this is an About page I don't think you need that.

Then, make and launch your form.

```
AboutBox frmAboutBox = new AboutBox();
frmAboutBox.Show();
```

You can also do `frmAboutBox.ShowDialog()` to make the newly hatch form always be on top.